# How to make translate.get() to return translation instead of key in angular?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using `ngx-translate` for doing my translations in my angular app, with `use()` is working perfectly the problem is when I use the `get(key)` method as is not returning the translated value, I have done some research and it seems to be an asynchronous problem as the get method is returning before I get the `JSON` file with the translations, how can I solve this situation?

This is how my `JSON` looks like

```js
info: {
    "EN": "English",
    "ES": "Spanish",
    "Register new device": "Registra un nuevo dispositivo",
   ... 
}
```

Here is my `app.module`

```js
export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: String){
    return this.http.get(API_URL+'/getLanguage/'+lang+'.json', httpOptions)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }) 
  ]
})
```

Here is my `service` where I use the methods from the library

```js
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class TranslateConfigService{
    language:any;
    constructor(private translateService:TranslateService){
        this.language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('language'))
        if(!this.language)this.translateService.use('en');
        else this.translateService.use(this.language);
    }
 
    changeLanguage(type:string) {
        localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(type));
        this.translateService.use(type);
    }

    getId(id){
        return this.translateService.get(id)
    }
}
```

Here is the function `translateKey()` I have it in every component and which is subscribing to the get response

```js
 buttonLabel: string = 'Register new device';
 language:any;
 activeItem: string;

constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateConfigService,
  ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('language'))
    if(!this.language)localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify("en"));
    this.activeItem = this.language;
    this.translateKey();
  }

 changeLang(type:string){
    this.setActiveItem(type)
    this.translateService.changeLanguage(type);
  }

 translateKey(){
    this.translateService.getId(this.buttonLabel)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.buttonLabel = res
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: what is the value in `this.buttonLabel`? I think you need to pass `this.activeItem` value  instead of `this.buttonLabel`

Comment: The value is `buttonLabel: string = 'Register new device';`

The `activeItem` variable is for managing some things in the HTML and doesn't need translation, the `buttonLabel` is the key that I need to be translated @RameshRajendran

Comment: is "Register new device" key for translation label?

Comment: @Chellappanவ Yes

Comment: can you share key translated json also?

Comment: Yes, please check my updated question 
Also here is my  `JSON`
 {
    "Register new device": "Registra un nuevo dispositivo",
   ... 
}

Comment: Can you try to call translateKey method inside setTimeout to check whether it's working or not?

Comment: I added the setTimeout and I'm still getting the key instead of the value, It's working perfectly with `use()` method but not for getting the keys I really don't understand very well why
`setTimeout(()=>{
        this.translateKey();
      },1000)
` 
@Chellappanவ

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve it, as all the translation information was inside a field that is called `info` in the JSON, I only had to make the reference to the field when using the get

```js
translateKey(langKey){
    this.translateService.getId("info."+langKey)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.buttonLabel = res
      }
    )
  }
```